# which library in pyspark implements graphx api

Tags: pyspark, spark-graphx

What is the library in pyspark that I can use for similar functionality as spark.graphx.GraphLoader. Basically I intend to import the following scala code to pyspark code.

'''
import org.apache.spark.graphx.GraphLoader
import org.apache.spark.sql.{SaveMode, SparkSession}

```
object FindTransMatch {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, World!")

        // Creates a SparkSession.
    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("FindTransMatch")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()
    val sc = spark.sparkContext

    val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, args(0),false)

    // Find the connected profiles
    val cc = graph.connectedComponents().vertices
    spark
      .sqlContext
      .createDataFrame(cc.toJavaRDD())
      .write
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).csv(args(1))
    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

'''

I tried installing graphframe from

but the setup.py has only following lines

```
# Your python setup file. An example can be found at:
# https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py
```

needless to say I did do

```
pip install graphframe
```

but  to no avail.

I saw here someone suggested using
'''
pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.7.0-spark2.3-s_2.11

'''

but I dont understand where to set this?

Comment: I needed to solve a problem using GraphX API. There is a GraphFrames library which provides python binds over the API. Here's an example which you can use as a reference.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76993984/3238085

Answer (score 0):

###### Adding the graphframes jar so that we can access GraphX API of Apache Spark in pyspark

### Jars can be found at this location : https://spark-packages.org/package/graphframes/graphframes

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("MyApp") \
    .config("spark.jars", "file:/path/to/spark-jars/graphframes-0.8.2-spark3.2-s_2.12.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()
```